# Python Twitter API TwitterError: user_id must be type int

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, twitter, python-twitter

I'm trying to use `python-twitter`. I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.omh.cc/blog/2008/aug/4/adding-your-twitter-status-django-site/).

Here is my code:

```
tweet = cache.get('tweet')

if not tweet:
    tweet = twitter.Api().GetUserTimeline(settings.TWITTER_USER)[0]
    tweet.date = datetime.strptime(tweet.created_at, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y")
    cache.set('tweet', tweet, settings.TWITTER_TIMEOUT)
```

But I'm getting next error:

```
Twitter.error.TwitterError: {'message': '"user_id" must be type int'}
```

I've set the variables like in the tutorial:

```
TWITTER_USER = 'CaseyNeistat'
TWITTER_TIMEOUT = 3600
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Evidently it wants the user ID (an integer), not the name (a string). Per [the README](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter/blob/master/README.rst), if you want to pass the name use the `screen_name` keyword argument.

Comment: @jonrsharpe but in the link I shared the author passed the string for TWITTER_USER

Comment: Maybe their article is wrong. Maybe the API changed and you're using a different version. The error message and current docs are pretty clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article got created about 9 years ago. So the API could changed many times since then.

Here is the signature of the function from [python-twitter documentation](http://python-twitter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/twitter.html?highlight=GetUserTimeline):

> GetUserTimeline(user_id=None, screen_name=None, since_id=None, max_id=None, count=None, include_rts=True, trim_user=False, exclude_replies=False)

So you want to do `GetUserTimeline(screen_name=settings.TWITTER_USER)`

Otherwise your string would go as `user_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `screen_name` as function argument.
For example, `GetUserTimeline(screen_name="elonmusk")`